# Multiple Pivots SQL SERVER 2008 on multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

This is my current dataset

```
select sampleId, plateID, target, confidence, zscore from Observations


sampleId   ||   plateID   ||    target   || confidence ||  zscore
-----------------------------------------------------------------
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||    I6-2D6   ||  < 0.50    ||   0.84
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||    E9-2D6   ||  > 0.99    ||   0.05
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||    I2-2D6   ||    0.99    ||   0.23
```

This is my dataset after one pivot to collapse the confidence column

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
SELECT sampleId, plateID, target, confidence, zscore
from Observations
) S
PIVOT( max(confidence) for target IN ([E9-2D6],[I6-2D6],[I2-2D6])) As confidence


sampleId   ||   plateID   ||  Zscore  ||   e9   ||   i6   ||   i2
-------------------------------------------------------------------
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||  0.02    || > 0.99 ||  NULL  ||  NULL
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||  0.25    ||  NULL  ||  NULL  ||  0.99
FR08512332 ||   13053620  ||  0.13    ||  NULL  || < 0.55 ||  NULL
```

This is the result i am looking to achieve

```
sampleId  || plateID  || conf-e9 || conf-i6 || conf-i2 || z-e9 || z-i6 || z-i2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FR08512332|| 13053620 || > 0.99  || < 0.55  ||  0.99   || 0.02 || 0.25 || 0.13
```

Comment: use one more aggregation

Comment: im fairly new to pivots, how would one go about doing this? thanks!

Comment: is the number of `target`s always fixed?

Comment: yes, there are only 3 targets

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation (easier to understand) instead of `pivot` as the number of targets are fixed.

[**Fiddle with sample data**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9e02e/9)

```
select sampleid, plateid,
max(case when target = 'I6-2D6' then confidence end) as conf_i6,
max(case when target = 'E9-2D6' then confidence end) as conf_e9,
max(case when target = 'I2-2D6' then confidence end) as conf_i2,
max(case when target = 'I6-2D6' then zscore end) as z_i6,
max(case when target = 'E9-2D6' then zscore end) as z_e9,
max(case when target = 'I2-2D6' then zscore end) as z_i2
from observations
group by sampleid, plateid
```

Comment: for learning purposes, how would i do it the alternate way with multiple pivots? thanks